# Autosys Machine Container

Tags: autosys

I am looking to set up a machine container in Autosys to look like the below example:

```
Example_Example_MAIN
Example_Example_MAIN.Machine_Name1
Example_Example_MAIN.Machine_Name2
Example_Example_MAIN.Machine_Name3
Example_Example_MAIN.Machine_Name4
```

The way i am currently controlling these machine is to send 2,3 & 4 Offline and leave 1 Online. Then if 1 goes Offline then i will send 2 Online and the batch will run on that machine.

Is it possible to leave all machines inside of a container Online but specify a machine priority? For example if i leave all machines Online then the batch will automatically target Machine_Name1 but if 1 goes Offline then the batch will automatically target machine 2 and so on.

Sorry if this is a silly question, i'm still only a beginner!

Thank you in advance!

Cameron.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can place all of your machines in a single pool. Autosys will only send jobs to the machines in the pool that are Online.

To do further load balancing than that, you'll have to configure the Factor (how fast it is relative to your other machines) and Max_Load (how much work it can handle at once) for every machine in the pool, as well as setting Job_Load units on each of your jobs indicating how much CPU they consume when running.

Refer to Chapter 3 of the Autosys user guide for the full details.